# How to get click on 'href' link using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

how do i click on the href link: href="/in/x-y-07976b159/" using selenium?

```
<a data-control-id="SOR2sXWgS8mDhCUEgFncpQ==" data-control-name="search_srp_result" href="/in/x-y- 
 07976b159/" id="ember1502" class="search-result__result-link ember-view">      <h3 id="ember1503" 
 class="actor-name-with-distance search-result__title single-line-truncate ember-view">  <span 
 class="name-and-icon"><span class="name-and-distance">
      <span class="name actor-name">x y</span>
         <span data-test-distance-badge="" id="ember1504" class="distance-badge separator ember-view"> 
           <span class="visually-hidden">
        1st degree connection
           </span>
          <span class="dist-value">1st</span>
        </span>
     </span><!----></span>
  </h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you get difficulty using `click()` ? Please post code snippet and error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can click it with the help of below command.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='ember1502']").click();
```

Where driver is the web driver instance.

Comment: Hi. this returns an empty list, thus not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both ways.

1) Find this element (eg. by id) and invoke method .click() on it.

2) Go to page (using driver.get(youcurrenturl + yourextracted href))

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing using `find_element_by_id`method.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.YourUrl.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('ember1502').click()
```

Comment: Hi this says there is NoSuchElement

Comment: My bad, the element id is ember1502, try it.